# Which dowel to use for drywall in front of brick wall with air inbetween?

Tags: drywall, brick

I want to hang something heavy so would prefer not just using the plaster wall. There is a gap of about two centimeters behind the plaster and then brick. What type of dowel would work best for this? Is there a way to fill the gap with something so it doesn't just dent in the plaster?[image]

Comment: Be more specific than "heavy." And is the weight tight to the wall? Or is it sitting on a shelf 10 inches from the wall? In the latter case your attachment positions become relevant. And how thick is the plaster?

Comment: There are spots somewhere that there isn't air between the plaster and brick. Find these spots and mount your heavy thing there.

Comment: Are you assuming that dowels must be involved in hanging something?

Comment: I'm not clear on where a dowel fits into this plan ...

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. We are trying to create some extra storage space by adding a shelve/floor above a door in the hallway (so between two walls meaning the weight is distributed straight down on each side). The board is only about 40cm deep and unfortunately there are no studs in that part of the wall. The plaster is not thick at all, one sheet probably 12.5 mm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dowels won't really work here. Best thing to do since this doesn't look to be really heavy (i.e. 50kgs plus) is to fill the gap with something which sets.

First set out and mark your placements, make the holes a little larger than you need, maybe one or even two centimetres in diameter. Mix up your material, best would be a drywall adhesive, alternatively any heavy wall filler, or hard backing plaster which is suitable for 2 to 3cm thickness will also work. Mix it fairly stiff so it doesn't drop down too much once in the holes.

Push the 'filler' into the holes, over and over and over again so that plenty has gone into the gap. Smooth off level with the wall and allow to set. You might need to top them up the next day if they shrink back a little.

Once fully dry, set out and drill your holes for the regular wall plugs and screws. You'll need pretty large plugs as the screws will be fairly long to ensure the plug is fully into the brickwork and definitely not just in the new filler/plaster.